# How to make the height of content div proportional?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div id=wrapper>
  <header>
  ...
  </header>

  <div id=content>
  ...
  </div>

  <footer>
  ...
  <footer>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
}
#content {
  height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

I would like to let `<header>` and `<footer>` always show up, and it is the `content div` that resizes according to height of the window.

But with the above CSS, if the height of the window is below a certain height, the `<footer>` would be out of the page. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `calc()`, supported **IE 9** +

The content div is given `height: calc(100% - 150px)`. That is, 100% of the page height minus the height of the header and footer. `overflow-y: auto` will scroll the content div to prevent content from spilling.

**A note on browser compatibility:** IE 8 and below will simply not give the content div a height. Depending on your needs, this may not be a problem. As a fallback, you could also provide a percentage height to the content div *above* the calc height so that IE 8 and below will have a non optimised height.

You can see a list of browser [support over here](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

[Read more about calc over on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #9c27b0;
}
#content {
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
    background: #f8bbd0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: #e91e63;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header></header>
        <div id="content"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```